# Why am I experiencing weird texture warping?

Tags: opengl

I'm using cubemaps to render a skybox, in my game. Thinking this would be a simple task, I threw some stuff together using the tutorials I found online, particularly [this one](http://www.keithlantz.net/2011/10/rendering-a-skybox-using-a-cube-map-with-opengl-and-glsl/). Taking all of this together, I then adjusted the program to compensate for my particularly junky Linux laptop, by converting the GLSL to 120. However, this turned sour when I discovered that the texture I was loading, which is just a straight black line meant to test this very issue, is being horribly bent by my program. A short clip of my problem is shown on [Youtube, here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC72UDtPlvU&feature=youtu.be). In desperation, I asked this question on gamedev.net, without much success.

---

My Shader code looks like this:

#### Vertex Shader

```
#version 120
attribute vec3 verPos;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform vec3 camPos;
varying vec3 texCoord;
void main(){

    vec4 vertexPosition = vec4(verPos, 1.0);
    texCoord = verPos;
    gl_Position = MVP * vertexPosition;

}
```

#### Fragment Shader

```
#version 120

varying vec3 texCoord;
uniform samplerCube CubeMap;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = textureCube(CubeMap, texCoord);
}
```

#### Rendering Code

To avoid being spammy, I'll just assume that I loaded the images correctly, and not show off that particular mess. I'm using `IMAGE_Load` from SDL2 to handle the texture loading, and I made the cube map clamp to edge and such.

```
void SkyBox::Draw(){
    if(!loadedCheck) return;
    glUseProgram(myProgID);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glm::mat4 perspect = glm::perspective(45.0f, float(640) / float(480), 0.1f, 3000.0f);
    vector3f playerPos = player.myNPC.myEnt.myObject.getPosition();
    float playerAngY = player.myNPC.myEnt.myObject.myAngle.y;

    camPos = glm::vec3(-15.0f * float(cos(-playerAngY + 1.62)), 0, 
        -15.0f *   float(sin(-playerAngY + 1.62)));

    //Convert my vector3f class to glm::vec3
    glm::vec3 playerGLM = glm::vec3(playerPos.x, playerPos.y, playerPos.z);
    float playerAngX = player.myNPC.myEnt.myObject.myAngle.x;

    //camPos is the position of the camera relative to the player's position
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(camPos + playerGLM, playerGLM, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
   // view = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(view));
   //To get rid of the translation matrix
    view[3][0] = 0;
    view[3][1] = 0;
    view[3][2] = 0;
    //comb is equivalent to an MVP matrix
    glm::mat4 comb = perspect * view;

    GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(myProgID, "MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(comb));


    GLuint camID = glGetUniformLocation(myProgID, "camPos");
    GLuint sampler = glGetUniformLocation(myProgID, "CubeMap");
    float camP[3] = {camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z};
    glUniform3fv(camID, 3, camP);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, myTexture);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(verAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        verAttrib, 
        3, 
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        0, 
        (void*)0
    );

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);


    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}
```

---

All in all, I feel like this should be working. Why am I experiencing weird texture warping?

Comment: The skybox looks fine for a moment when looking into a perpendicular face (ie. 90,180,270 degrees), like it's rotating in the opposite direction. It may be an issue with how you calculate the camera's position for the matrix calcs using the angles.

Comment: I meant to rotate it in the opposite direction along with the terrain because of the character's rotation. You also mentioned the camera's positioning as an issue, though I'm not sure how that would cause the texture to bend.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what happens if you load up some proper cube test faces marked as "+X", "-X", "+Y", "-Y" etc. Then you can at least see if it's happening on particular faces, or if something else is going wrong. It's kind of hard to tell with just a black line *what's* going bad.